# Equation 3.6 Elements of Causal Inference

Tags: causality

I am reading Elements of Causal Inference by Peters et al.

On page 36 they are giving an example with the following SCM:

$$T := N_T$$
$$B := T\cdot N_B + (1 - T)\cdot(1 - N_B)$$

On the equation 3.6, when talking about counterfactuals, they condition the SCM $\mathfrak{C}$ on $\mathfrak{C} | B=1, T=1$, with the SCM becoming:

$$T := 1$$
$$B := T\cdot 1 + (1 - T)\cdot(1 - 1)=T$$

Which doesn't make sense to me anymore.
When we condition on $B=1$ shouldn't the SCM simply become

$$T := 1$$
$$B := 1$$

?

Shouldn't we be conditioning on $N_B = 1$ and $N_T = 1$ only?

Furthermore, had we conditioned on $T=0, B=1$ following the model of the book, wouldn't we fall into a contradiction where $B:=T$ and $B=1$ and $T=0$?

Answer (score 1):

Your second and third pair of equations are the same, so there is no contradiction as far as I can see.
The conditioning on $B, T$ is done to determine the value of $N_B$, which is otherwise unknown, so there is no way to condition on it.
If $T=0$ and $B=1$, $N_B$ must have been equal to 0.

Comment: So your point is that we are unable to condition on the Noise variables because they are unknown and unobservable, and thus they condition on B and T only to discover what would happen to $N_B$ and $N_T$ and then they replace the values of the Noise variables on the SCM to produce the new SCM $\mathfrak{C}|B=1,T=1$?

Comment: The conditioning on $B$ and $T$ is not done to to infer what _would happen_, but rather _what must have happened_ to $N_B$. This is essential to the idea of counterfactuals. For counterfactual reasoning we first have to know every part of the system that lead to the "factual" outcome, to then be able to hypothetically change some of them and look at what would have been the "counterfactual" outcome.